# How to remove 2 decimal places without rounding in a running total in CR?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a number field in my database that contains four decimal places. I have a running total in my Crystal Report that sums this field. I am attempting to not round and only show 2 decimal places.

Example:
My running total displays 809.47
I want it to show 809.46

Since the field from the database produces a sum of 809.4680, how can I just make it 809.46?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: truncate(809.468,2) = 809.460

Comment: So would you create a formula with the field prior to creating the running total? Also, if I wanted it to display as 809.46, wouldn't I put the comma after the 6? And if I were to create a formula, would I use zeros?

Example: 0000000.00,2

Thank you for your help!

Comment: After  you have placed the RT on the report,right click and use the Format options, you can customise how you want it to be displayed.